# word choice "apply for" or "apply to"

Tags: prepositional-verbs

Reading [this article](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/apply-to-apply-for-and-apply-with/) on DailyWritingTips that explains the difference between "apply for " and "apply to"

> **apply to**
> This is the idiom to use when you are putting yourself forward as a candidate for something such as a course of study, or a job. You apply to graduate school. You apply to a company for employment. You apply to a bank’s loan department for a loan.
>
> **apply for**
> This is the expression to use if your intention is to obtain something. You apply for scholarship money. You apply for admission. You apply for a job.

I am still puzzled about why the correct sentence is

> (a) Winston is **applying to** the teaching program at Harvard.

and not

> (b) Winston is **applying for** the teaching program at Harvard.

Is not the teaching program that Winston wants?
Winston wants to obtain the teaching program so he "apply for" it.

Answer (score -1):

Just as your cited article says:

> Winston is applying ***to*** Harvard.
>
> Winston is applying ***for*** teaching certification.

Comment: So it is correct to say "Winston is applying for the teaching program at Harvard."

Comment: Err, no, "Winston is applying **to** the teaching program at Harvard. He is applying **for** a teaching degree."

Comment: My basic understanding is that you "apply to (somewhere)" while you "apply for (something)".

Comment: My understanding is that one apply to an "institute," so the teaching program is, in a sense, an organization that deals with teaching degrees, am I right?

Comment: Yet if it were written at the top of the form Winston fills out, it would certainly not say "Application To A Teaching Degree".   Rather, "for" would be used.   Both occur and there are no good rules here, one must just listen and imitate.