# Apply to/for with name of program

Tags: word-choice

Does one say:

Application **for** [name] program
or
Application **to** [name] program

in American English ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [word choice "apply for" or "apply to"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/191076/word-choice-apply-for-or-apply-to)

Comment: What kind of program? At a college? Or a TV program? Or computer?

Answer (score 1):

You would apply *for* something you would get, like an internship or scholarship.

> I'm applying for an internship at Universal Studios.

You would apply *to* something you would join or the entity that awards.

> I'm applying to the Disney College Program.

Comment: Your example "I'm applying the Disney College Program" is ungrammatical for this meaning, and both "applying for an internship" and "applying to an internship" are in common use.

Comment: @BadZen Sorry, no.  I'm again 100% correct.  Please stop, it's not a good look.  From the DCP: https://support.disneyprograms.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015145732

Comment: @BadZen Perhaps this is a regionalism, but in the United States, no one says, "I am playing TO an internship". It is always, "I am applying FOR an internship". As Johns says, you apply "to" an organization. Like you might say, "I am applying to XYZ Corporation for an internship."

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22applying+to+an+internship%22 (about 4,220,000 results)

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22applying+to+an+internship%22 (about 990,000 results)

Comment: This isn't really a great way to do statistical linguistics, but should be persuasive to you that both forms are used.   Notice how many of the documents /use both forms/, with "to" and with "for", in the very same speech sample.

Comment: It's maybe easy to confuse "I'm not used to saying it in this way" with "no one ever says it this way!", especially if you're new to thinking about evaluating usage.   But if you see many examples of use, and you insist that it's wrong or in some other way invalid, it's a pretty weird hill to choose to die on.

Comment: @BadZen Nope.  You don't apply to an internship.  They're also using it wrong.  I quite confident I will not die, or even be slightly embarrassed on this hill.

Comment: All 990,000 of them?   Because you say so?

Comment: @BadZen Yes, all 990,000.  Because of how the Internet works, a lot of these are duplicative and Google just amplifies that.  So, in conclusion, you don't apply to an internship because...well, you just don't. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/apply-for

Comment: Did you even try looking in CD for "apply-to"?  This is not rhetorical, but a serious question I want you to answer.   (If you did not, why did you not?)

Comment: @BadZen Of course I did, and *apply for* specifically uses "scholarship" which I used in my 100% correct answer alongside internship.  "Roger applied for a scholarship to Yale."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147591/discussion-between-badzen-and-johns-305).